# How to parse JSON response from API in Xamarin

Tags: json, xamarin, httprequest, httpresponse

I am fairly new to Xamarin and doing my first project. I have a problem where I need to sign in a user and retrieve details from response. This is what my **JSON request** looks like:

**JSON Request:**

```
'{
"key": "value",
"key": "value",

"JsonReq": {

    "JHeader": {
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value"
    },

    "JMetaData": {},

    "JData": {
        "key": "value",
        "key": "value"
    }
},

"key": "value"}'
```

**The request JSON is enclosed in single quotes.**

I have written a **model class** (using online JSON to C-sharp tool) in Xamarin and I can successfully send a POST request to the API and get a proper response. The **JSON response** looks something like this:

**JSON Response:**

```
{
\"JHeader\": {
    \"key\": IntegerValue,
    \"key\": \"value\"
},

\r \"JMetaData\": {

    \"Headings\": [
        [\"list1\", \"listItem\", \"ListItem\"],
        [\"list2\", \"listItem\", \"ListItem\"],
        \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[\"list3\",\t\t\t\t\t \"listItem\",\t\t\t \"ListItem\"]
    ]
},

\r \"JData\": [
    \r [\"listItem\", \"listItem\", \"ListItem\"]
]}
```

**The response JSON is NOT enclosed in single quotes.** But has these \r \t and \

Now I want to parse this response and extract values from it. But since there are some differences between the request and response, I am unable to use the same model class for both. For example, there is no "JSonReq" in response but one exists in request. "JMetaData" is a **list** type in response but has key-value pairs in the request.

Any ideas how to parse this response?

Comment: that is not valid json.  Instead of posting "something like this" please post the actual response you receive, or a representative sample.  Have you tried running the response through the same json2csharp tool you used for the request?

Comment: @Jason yes this is not a valid JSON. But I can fix it by removing \r \t and \. Then it becomes a valid JSON. Yes I have run the response from json2csharp after fixing it and it generates the c-sharp code. But here is what happens next. Now my project will have two model classes; one for request and one for response and both of them will have JHeader and JMetada classes. How can I have two classes of same name in a single namespace?

Answer (score 0):

generate a model for your response, like this

```
public class JHeader    {
    public string key { get; set; } 
}

public class JMetaData    {
    public List<List<string>> Headings { get; set; } 
}

public class Root    {
    public JHeader JHeader { get; set; } 
    public JMetaData JMetaData { get; set; } 
    public List<List<string>> JData { get; set; } 
}
```

then parse it using [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Comment: Yes I have already tried that. But I already have these classes in the request model. Can I have two classes of same name in a single namespace? Plus JData is a class in request and a list in response.

Comment: I think I got it. I was thinking maybe I could not change the class names as they were being used to generate the json. Just figured it was not the case and I only need to keep the variable names same as in the request and response not the class names. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I was thinking maybe I could not change the class names as they were being used to generate the json. Just figured it was not the case and I only need to keep the variable names same as in the request and response, and not the class names. Silly me.